# Changing style of checked radio button in React.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have some radio buttons which I've styled to look like this:

[image]

As of now they look the same even when checked. I want to make it so that when you check one, instead of just being a ring, it's filled in with the same color like this:

[image]

How would I do this in React? I can add a background color to the element in the CSS but it won't be each element's own color (unless I create a separate class for each element but that seems very long considering I have a lot of these).

Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Options from './Options.jsx';

class Icing extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Options>
                <input type="radio" className="circle" name="icing" defaultValue={1} id="white" style={{border: "10px solid #EFE5CE"}} />
                <label class="radio" htmlFor="white"></label>
                <input type="radio" className="circle" name="icing" defaultValue={2} id="pink" style={{border: "10px solid #EF959D"}} />
                <label class="radio" htmlFor="pink"></label>
                <input type="radio" className="circle" name="icing" defaultValue={3} id="red" style={{border: "10px solid #90DDD0"}} />
                <label class="radio" htmlFor="red"></label>
            </Options>
        );
    }
};

export default Icing;
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Alright so I added this:

```
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {checked: false};
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange() {
        this.setState({
            checked: !this.state.checked
        })
    }
```

And this to the button as a test:

```
onChange={this.handleChange} checked={this.state.checked} style={{backgroundColor: this.state.checked ? 'red' : 'white'}}
```

And sure enough the background does change on click, but it doesn't go back to normal when I click another button. I have to click it again to make the color disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onChange` input's attribute to handle a check. In the handle function, you can change component's `state`. Use state to set style. For example:

```
style={{backgroundColor: this.state.isCheck ? 'red': 'white'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control CSS with javascript in React.

```
render() {

  const styles = {
    radioWhite: {
      border: "10px solid #90DDD0",
    },
    radioPink: {
      border: "10px solid #EF959D",
    },
    radioRed: {
      border: "10px solid #90DDD0",
    }
  };

  // pink on click
  styles.radioPink['backgroundColor'] = '#EF959D';

  return (
    <Options>
      <input type="radio" className="circle" name="icing" defaultValue={1} id="white" style={styles.radioWhite} />
      <label class="radio" htmlFor="white"></label>
      <input type="radio" className="circle" name="icing" defaultValue={2} id="pink" style={styles.radioPink} />
      <label class="radio" htmlFor="pink"></label>
      <input type="radio" className="circle" name="icing" defaultValue={3} id="red" style={styles.radioRed} />
      <label class="radio" htmlFor="red"></label>
    </Options>
  );
}
```

I have more examples in my react-gallery project:
https://github.com/bfwg/relay-gallery